# android file not working with numpy recipe

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am using example from Kivy documentation, only line i added is import numpy. After packaging it for android i cant run on my phone it never starts. However on removing this line and then building works fine.

python file: main.py

```
__version__="1.0.0"
import colorsys
import numpy as np
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def animate(self, instance):
        animation = Animation(pos=(100, 100), t='out_bounce')
        animation += Animation(pos=(200, 100), t='out_bounce')
        animation &= Animation(size=(500, 500))
        animation += Animation(size=(100, 50))
        animation.start(instance)
    def build(self):
        button = Button(size_hint=(None, None), text='plop',
                    on_press=self.animate)
        return button
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

In buildozer.spec file under requirement i have included kivy, numpy.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the log](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) to see what's wrong.